# SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis 00906. 00000 - "missing left parenthesis"

Tags: oracle

i have been trying to make a simple table and i it keeps coming up with SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis 00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"

```
CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE(
USER_ID int NOT NULL,
Username varchar NULL,
Password varchar NULL, 
Email varchar NOT NULL,
DOB Date NULL, 
Address VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
First_name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
Telephone_number int NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (User_ID));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add the size of VARCHAR colums:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE
(
    USER_ID             INT NOT NULL,
    Username            VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    Password            VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    Email               VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    DOB                 DATE NULL,
    Address             VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    First_name          VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Telephone_number    INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(User_ID)
);
```

Notice that `VARCHAR` is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90120/ch4_dep.htm#10006), better use `VARCHAR2`

Comment: _deprecated_ may not be the best word. It is not deprecated but reserved for future use. So it may change its behaviour.